# How can I show the post thumbnail from the most recent of a certain post type, in widget?

Tags: php, loop, post-thumbnails

I'm using the excellent [PHP Code Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/) plugin, and want to create a widget that displays the post thumbnail (aka featured image) for the most recent 'project' post. Here's the code I have so far, but it isn't producing the desired result. This actually outputs nothing.

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    ); 
$thumbnails = get_posts($args);
foreach ($thumbnails as $post)
{
    setup_postdata($post);
        ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?></a>
        <?php 
        }
```

Any suggestions on what I need to change for this to work?

Comment: _Nothing_ like not even empty markup for link tag? Had you checked that post is returned at all and `$thumbnails` is not empty?

Comment: Correct, nothing at all. What is the best way to check $thumbnails? If I use "print_r($thumbnails);", I get "Array ( )" as the output.

Comment: Turns out I wasn't using the correct slug for the post type. It should have been 'projects'. Thanks for the suggestion to check $thumbnails, that's what got me thinking about why it was empty. It works now, except I get three featured images, instead of the 1 I expected. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving here so comments don't turn into a mess.

Basically there are two things that can go wrong here:

1. Fetching of posts. Check that `$thumbnails` gets correct post and only one. I am not sure if that is the issue, but `get_posts()` docs list `numberposts` argument instead of `posts_per_page` that is listed for `query_posts()`. That might make a difference.
2. Messing with global variables. For this usage I wouldn't touch global `$post` at all, directly or with `setup_postdata()` either. Just use non-loop versions of functions that can fetch things you need by post id - [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) and [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail).

Comment: Using numberposts did indeed fix it. Interesting, since the Codex says that get_posts() "can also take the parameters that query_posts() can".

I think I understand #2 - I'll see if I can successfully re-write it and come back if that doesn't work out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, most of the time `query_posts()` and `get_posts()` are identical. But they do have some differences in internals and default arguments, so I try to stick with what docs say when arguments do seemingly same thing.

Comment: Just FYI, looks like this has been fixed: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15150